# Textbox validation in C# Winforms - Should allow only numerics between 1-100

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

Hello Sorry its a simple question, but would appreciate if someone can guide me with the code. I have say 50 textboxes in my Winform. All should allow only numeric values and that too between 1-100 only. How should I ensure this validation?

My thoughts was using e.Keychar in keypress event using Ascii values to restrict users to type only numerics. Also, probably I can ensure this validation in Set in the property? But I don't know if I am correct and also don't know right code. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of normal `TextBox` box with validation.

> A NumericUpDown control contains a single numeric value that can be
>   incremented or decremented by clicking the up or down buttons of the
>   control. The user can also enter in a value, unless the ReadOnly
>   property is set to true.

You can specify the minimum and maximum numbers, it will allow the user to enter numbers between 1 and 100 and also let them use up and down buttons.

EDIT: If you want to do it through code then you can try something like in `KeyPress` event of your `TextBox`:

```
private void yourTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The above can be improved to access `.` for decimal numbers, but I guess you got the idea.

Comment: @Habib: Thanks :( I got my interview flucked :( Interviewer confused me and I just told what I wrote above :( He was again and again asking me. I never got an idea of NumericUpDOwn. Thank you Habib. But if I have to ask you how to do custom validation, any pointers for my situation please? A small code snippet would help me understand

Comment: @Divine, just updated my answer with the code, you can do that in ` `KeyPress` event like in the answer, it can definitely be improved, but just wanted to give you an idea

Comment: @Habib: Thank you so much. However the above code will allow values beyond 100? Or is that something that is homework for me? :) I am happy to do that if so. Well anyway, its a learning, it can be useful for my future interviews

Comment: @Divine, you can check the ascii values to see if it is between 1 and 100, you can parse it to int and see if it is between 1 and 100, many ways...., its for you to figure it out,

Comment: @Habib: Thank you so much, I will do it today itself and learn it :) :) Your input helped me a lot.... :) Cheers